# Active Admin not displaying Label names correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, activeadmin

In my app I have `categories` and `labels`  they both belongs to `products`

In the admin panel the user can add products, and create labels and categories  and then assign categories and labels to products.

When I create labels the names are displaying correctly in the Label Panel( see photo)

[image]

The Problem is that the labels name aren't displaying right when they are assign to products(see photo below) but the categories names are displaying.  This is strange because both columns have the same setup.

And in the `Admin products panel` the labels are displaying with numbers ``` Label#1``Label#2 ```etc (see photo below)

And in the `_navbar.html.erb` I have this code to display Both Categories and Labels... and it is displaying correctly in there.

```
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
                        <li><%= link_to category.name, category %></li>
                    <% end %>         
                </ul>
            </li>       
              <li class="dropdown full-width">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
                data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Labels
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                   <% @labels.each do |label| %>
                        <li><%= link_to label.label_name, label %></li>
                    <% end %>    
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Am I missing something here? I can't see why the labels aren't displaying correctly.

Have anyone had the same or similar problem with active admin?

Can anyone take a look at this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the `app/admin/category.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do

 permit_params :name

end
```

In the `app/admin/label.rb` there is this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Label do

 permit_params :label_name

end
```

And in the `app/admin/product.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do


 permit_params :title, :description, :image, :price_usd, :price_isl, :category_id, :label_id

 index do
    column :title
    column :category
    column :label
    column :created_at

    column :price_isl, :sortable => :price_isl do |product|
        number_to_currency product.price_isl
    end
    column :price_usd, :sortable => :price_usd do |product|
        number_to_currency product.price_usd
    end

    actions
end
end
```

Then here are parts of the Schema.rb

```
create_table "labels", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "label_name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Active Admin makes educated guesses when displaying objects.

This is the list of methods it tries calling in order

- display_name
- full_name
- name
- username
- login
- title
- email
- to_s

So, it works with categories since Category has `:name` attribute.

For `labels` you can do the following:

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
    def display_name
      label_name
    end
end
```

You can also configure displayed names in ActiveAdmin initializer:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|    
  config.display_name_methods = [:display_name, :full_name, :name, ..., :to_s]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin can sometimes be tricky with naming...In your `categories`table you have a `column` called `:name` which seems to be working like you want it to?

have you tried to change the `label_name`column in the `labels.rb`to just names?

I'm pretty sure that will do the trick for you.

Active Admin is most likely not registering the underscore between `label`and `name`and thats way its displaying things like it is.

Comment: Thank you sometimes it's the simple things that you don´t see :) It's working perfectly now